# I want to convert range got from range.js to comma seperated values

Tags: range

```html
<input multiple="multiple" name="year[]" type="hidden" class="range-slider" value="2004,2014" style="display: none;">
```

here is my code

this input field provide range as value. I want to convert it to comma seperated strings as

```
2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014
```

how can i do it using javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var a = $('.range-slider').val().split(',');
var tmp = [];
for(i = a[0];i <= a[1];i++){
  tmp.push(i);
}
console.log(tmp.join());
```

I used JQuery in order to select the value, but you can use whatever you want.